# Can I have 2 JQuery functions that overlaping each other, running in 1 page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HI I got some problem implemented 2 jquery in a html page
this is the query im using:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blinds-0.9.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">                  //running the script for blinds
    $(window).load(function () {
            // start the slideshow
    $('.slideshow').blinds();
    })
    </script>



<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">              //running the script for accordion
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#accordion").accordion();
});
</script>
```

The problem is only 1 script can run if I implement them both in html (either accordion or blinds), does anyone know how to modify them so all the jquery can run, and I can reuse them throughout a page?

e.g blinds wont run if i add the accordion js reference to the head.

Answer would be most appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the error message from the Javascript console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

only one runs because the other is executed before jQuery was loaded

try:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>              <!--jQuery-->
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>           <!--jQueryUI plugin-->
<script src="js/jquery.blinds-0.9.js"></script>    <!--blinds plugin-->
<script>                                           <!--your scripts-->
    $(function() {
        $('#accordion').accordion();
        $('.slideshow').blinds();
    });
</script>
```

And [jQueryUI has a built-in blinds effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/). You might not need the blinds plugin if it does the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to clean up the order in which you call the scripts. Let jQuery load first, then all the other libraries and your custom script last. You might also want to save it into an external JS file for improved maintenance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.blinds-0.9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/javascript/foo.js"></script>
```

Also, the attribute `language="Javascript"` is redundant and can be safely removed.

Inside the `foo.js` file, use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // start the slideshow & accordion
    $('.slideshow').blinds();
    $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

The difference here is that you use `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`. Also, you need to invoke the `$(document).ready()` only once, not twice.

Hope that helps.